# Persist data between pages in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Sometimes you want to call `router.navigate` to a new location, but send data to that page without placing it in the URL, for example, a complex object that has been manipulated in the first page.

How is that accomplished in Angular2?

Comment: You can use a service to store that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular2 it's accomplished through dependency injection. You are using shared service between components and retrieve data  in `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: So you're saying I specifically should create a service to persist that data between pages>

Comment: so i saying yes